How to completely override code for ConfirmSignUp in AWS Amplify with React UI
I am using AWS Amplify with React and trying to build a custom authentication flow with the following requirements:

The user fills out a registration form.
After submitting the form, the user should see a static message like "Your application is under review. You will be notified via email about the outcome."
The user remains in the UNCONFIRMED state in Cognito, and an admin manually decides whether to confirm or reject the user.

In Cognito configuration I have selfSignUp enabled, but auto verification is disabled.
The point is, after filling out the form by user it still shows the page with "Your code is on the way. To log in, enter the code we sent you. It may take a minute to arrive.", field to pass verification code and button submit. Obviously I do want user to confirm process. How to get rid of this view?
I see I only play with Footer and Header:
const components = {
  ConfirmSignUp: {
    Header() {
      return (
          <Typography variant="body2" sx={{textAlign: 'center', marginTop: '16px'}}>
            Header. ConfirmSignUp. Your application is under review. You will receive an email once it has been verified.
          </Typography>
      );
    },
    Footer() {
      return (
          <Typography variant="body2" sx={{ textAlign: 'center', marginTop: '16px' }}>
           ConfirmSignUp!
          </Typography>
      );
    },
  }
};

How to bypass it?
